# What does "high" in "talking in high circles" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> he walks and talks in high circles so other people take him for his word.

What does *high* in “talking in high circles” mean?

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+in+circles says

> talk in circles

> To talk about something in an indirect or confusing way that fails to directly answer or address something or which keeps returning to the same points.

> As journalists, we need to ask the important questions and keep these politicians from talking in circles.
> A: "So, what exactly do you think we should do about this issue?" B: "I don't really know. I'm just talking in circles at this point."

The first quote is from a dialogue:

> A: Narcissism and perfectionism are two features that reflect our
> time. The majority of people are just like that. If you accept
> yourself and try to get along with others, then everything will be
> fine and no one will be offended
>
> F:  I’d like to think that were true but various manifestations with
> regards to my sister’s ex and his propensity for verbally trashing
> people he doesn’t like and imaginatively turning people he suddenly
> has no regard for into monsters would propel me to second guess that.
>
> A:  more likely it’s a pathological behavior or just another pathology
>
> F:  Yes it is….or at least my sister’s counselor has listed it as
> such. However, he walks and talks in high circles so other people take
> him for his word (as did my sister at one time).

Comment: Where did you get that sentence? Because there are two idioms to take him **at his word**. And **to talk in circles**. For that second idiom, it would be a mistake to add an adjective.

Comment: "walk and talk to people in high circles" is meaningless.

Comment: What's the source? There are users arguing whether  "he walks and talks in high circles” is acceptable, completely understandable, a deliberate variant of the idiom, "rubbish", a clever play on words… So, please cite the source. If this snippet came from a Chinese translation we need to know that too.

Answer (score 3):

It refers to exclusive and powerful social groups, often associated with wealth, political influence, or social prestige. These circles might involve celebrities, politicians, business leaders, and so on.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean circle means social circle? See my update

Comment: No, it is a mistake in the idiom. He moves in high circles, OK.

Comment: It might be a deliberate variation in the idiom rather than a mistake. But it's hard to know from the question.

Comment: I think this answer is likely to be correct because the original phrase includes "so other people take him at his word".   He's someone with access to power.

Comment: @TimR This is a "correct-my-sentence" question and even by correcting the idiom to take him at his word, it still wouldn't make much sense. He hangs out with people in high circles, granted. "walks and talks in high circles"? No-go.

Comment: @Lambie   Sometimes your comments make no sense to me and this is one of those times. Maybe I'm obtuse, but I don't see any request for correction there but a request for an explanation of what the phrase means. I see it as StuartF tentatively saw it, as "a deliberate variation on the idiom rather than a mistake".  To call it as you do a "no-go" is to be awfully  rigid in one's sense of what can be done expressively with the English language.

Comment: @TimR Allow me. A person *can move*  in high circles (presumably social circles), but would you seriously accept: "walks and talks in high circles"?? That is simply flat out wrong. But one can imagine: he walks and talks in complete circles [OK]. *That works. BUT*: it cannot be joined to the other one: "walks and talks in complete circles so other people take him at his word". Absurd right? It is my view that questions like this are looking for corrections and/or editing. The OP found (presumably) talk in circles, and then added high to it. It is a no-go. Do you prefer does not make sense?

Comment: I think he might mean in fact: **He moves in high circles so people take him at his word**. That does make sense. But have I not just corrected two idiom errors and now rewritten it so it makes sense? OK, so the OP found it online. Doesn't make it any better.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, if I were grading a paper I would allow "walks and talks in high circles" as a somewhat fanciful extension of the common idiom (perhaps less fanciful than "She walks in beauty"), though I would mark "take him for his word" as inadmissible. Meanwhile, knowing that this was off-the-cuff conversation makes this answer clearly the _intent_, whether or not the speaker should have reworded, as opposed to Tim's initial confusion with "talk in circles."

Comment: @AndyBonner That's you. To me it is a completely mixed metaphor. She walks in high circles? She mixes in high circles. Of course, when we speak off the cuff we are wont to do these things. Nevertheless, it still requires disentangling for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

That dialogue is faulty because the person was speaking off the cuff and didn't do it so well:

**The idea** is:
He *moves in high circles* so people take him *at his word*.

to *move in high circles* [*high social circles*]
to live and breathe in high circles

to *walk and talk in high circles* is just rubbish, poorly said.

You can *walk and talk in circles*, same as: walk and talk going around in circles. That's acceptable but that is not the meaning here.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with something StuartF tenatively suggested in a comment might be the case: "It might be a deliberate variation in the idiom rather than a mistake." But I think it is also a (deliberate) conflation with another idiom.

In American English (and perhaps also in BrE) we say "If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it probably is a duck".

To say that someone "Walks  and talks in high circles" evokes that saying about the duck: he walks and talks in high circles replaces "move" in the idiomatic expression "to move in high circles", and suggests that, well, he probably legitimately belongs in high circles. He's legit. He frequents the "upper echelons" of power and influence mentioned in the answer by @Samis.

This understanding of the remark  as a witty conflation of two idioms is borne out by a later edit to the question, where OP cites where the phrase was found:

> {snip}
>
> A: more likely it’s a pathological behavior or just another pathology
>
> F: Yes it is….or at least my sister’s counselor has listed it as such. However, he [i.e. the person assessed as being pathological] **walks and talks in high circles so other people take him for his word** (as did my sister at one time).
> [my emphasis]

Other people think he is a legitimate judge of character because of the company he keeps; they believe what he says when trashing the people he doesn't like.

He walks in high circles and talks in high circles and so he probably belongs in high circles and knows what he's talking about.